# Tag cleanup: Delete tag [rows]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-cleanup-request

[rows](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/rows)

> A row is a horizontal line of something within a program. It can be a row of cells in excel, or a row of text in a text document. Rows are horizontally positioned and are generally read left-to-right.

There are 31 questions tagged with this tag, majority of them is related to spreadsheet applications. I don't think [rows] adds anything to the value of questions.

Comment: The explanation isn't even accurate (a number of language versions read right to left, and that phrase is irrelevant to the definition).  "Program" isn't a good choice of words because it generally applies to documents rather than code.  Aside from that, do we have users who are experts on "rows" (we wouldn't want to trust a "columns" expert on a "rows" question)?  How do we get tags like this in the first place?

Comment: Title suggestion: `After a row with [rows]...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: Delete option selected on the row]

[image: "rows" row is gone]

RIP [rows](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/rows): February 29, 2012 - July 4, 2016.

As usual, I made sure to fix all other obvious problems with each question in addition to removing the tag.