# Lyse the [cells]

Tags: discussion, tag-cleanup-request

Similarly to my previous question: [Tag cleanup: Delete tag [rows]](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/11615/tag-cleanup-delete-tag-rows), I think we don't have experts on [cells](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/cells) and adding this tag to questions doesn't increase their value , so we could get rid of it.

Comment: If you're going to post these kinds of questions, you need to come up with more clever titles.  :-)

Comment: I, personally, wouldn't use "Apoptosis for [cells]", but I'll toss it out there just to get ideas flowing.

Comment: @fixer1234 We could **[lyse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lysis)** the cells!

Comment: It's a break out - destroy the [cells]